# Error when loading texture with SOIL_load_OGL_texture

Tags: c++, opengl, soil

I'm currently working on a little 3d renderer and was trying to add textures. Thing is when I try to load the texture using SOIL_load_OGL_texture I get an access violation error with vcruntime140d.dll .

I saw another post here with a similar error, but it was coming from the fact that the user had apparently not created an OpenGL context when trying to load the texture, which I have done.

The error has something to do with a string being a nullptr int the strstr() function of vcruntime140d.dll

Here is a screenshot of the call stack : [call stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liqEK.png)

EDIT : here is code producing the error :

```
std::string stringPath = texturePath.string();

std::cout << "Loading texture : " << stringPath.c_str() << std::endl;

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

GLuint textureID = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(stringPath.c_str(), SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_POWER_OF_TWO | SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS);

if (textureID == 0)
{
    printf("SOIL loading error: '%s'\n", SOIL_last_result());
    return -1;
}

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);

m_textures.emplace(texturePath, textureID);

return textureID;
```

Comment: I tried using SOIL_load_image instead and it now works, I don't really understand why though.

Comment: Do you have a valid OpenGL context at that point? What is the exact error message? Access violation reading/writing ... or Access violation executing ...? The only use of `strstr` in SOIL is `strstr( (char const*)glGetString( GL_EXTENSIONS ))`.

Comment: I have a valid OpenGL context I believe since I can render geometry (just not with textures)

I get an access violation error when reading

The exact error is :
    Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC41651C77 (vcruntime140.dll) in game.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000

Comment: What's your OpenGL context version and is it a Core or Compatibility profile?

Comment: I tried it with OpenGL 3.3 and 4.4, both with Core and Compatibility profile

Comment: Wow, the issue, whatever it was, just decided to magically resolve itself. I still don't understand the least bit what was causing it, nor what I did to fix it, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Okay my bad it's back.

It seems to have to do with my integrated graphics chipset not being able to use glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D), even with a Compatibility profile, while my graphics card can handle it.